# Flink Statefun Broadcast state feature

Tags: apache-flink, flink-statefun

Is there a broadcast state feature available in Flink Statefun, just like Apache Flink ([Broadcast State Pattern](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/broadcast_state/)) ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built-in support for broadcasting messages; the built-in messaging always involves sending messages to specific addresses.

You can, however, implement a pub-sub model yourself, by having subscribers register their interest with a function that acts as a message broker.

Comment: Sounds good.  Thanks David.

Comment: How would you do that, if the subscriber functions have really many IDs, say 50 million? I guess storing so many target IDs in the broker function would be too much for the way state is handled for remote functions (sending it over HTTP).